# in calculator Plus button design so that it is not written for the first time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]this is my code :

```
function press_button(value) {

    const x = document.getElementById("for_dis").innerHTML;

    if(x == 0 && value == "+"){
    document.getElementById("for_dis").innerHTML = 0 ; 
};
```

I want it not to show the value when I press the apply math button for the first time because then it is considered a bug. For the first time "+ - / * " do nothing.

Comment: you are overcomplicating the issue. Simply define the start value as 0. There are reasons to actually use a + or minus at the start. If I want to start with a negative number as an example. PS: you should not `innerHTML` it is slow and poses a security issue (XSS). You would be better off with `textContent` or better yet with  an input and then using `value`

Comment: No, pay attention to the picture of the console part
I started with zero and set the initial value to zero, but the thing that it should not show it by pressing the + button and.. and the value should not change from zero.
I have set the initial value to zero, but in this picture I have pressed the + button once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by defining a flag in such a way that in the first case, the value of the flag is false by default, and to prevent entering mathematical operations.
When the numeric button is pressed, the value of the flag will change to true and we can enter math operations.